# Designing a HTML form based on a layout which involves labels, textboxes and a div placeholder

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a particular form in HTML and I drew a draft in which I would like to achieve the below layout:

[image]

"**Title**", "**Category**" and "**LeaseNumber**" are labels, followed by **textboxes** and the **blue square** represents a **placeholder div** in which I will **add a background image** to it.

I'm having issues achieving the layout like the image above, would appreciate some help on this. I have the following right now:

[image]

```css
.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.small_output_field {
    width: 5%;
}

.long_output_field {
    width: 15%;
}

#img_placeholder {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>houseform</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "outer">
        <div class = "form_fields_short">
            <label id = "title">Title</label>
            <input type = "text" id = "title_field" class = "small_output_field">
        </div>
        <div class = "form_fields_short">
            <label id = "category">Category</label>
            <input type = "text" id = "cat_field" class = "small_output_field">
        </div>
        <div id = "img_placeholder">
    
        </div>
        <div class = "form_fields_long">
            <label id = "lease">LeaseNumber</label>
            <input type = "text" id = "lease_field" class = "long_output_field">
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: the easiest way to do it is with the use of a CSS-Grid. If nobody else will do it within the enxt 30minutes, I will it do it for you then (still got work to do).

Answer (score 1):

As promised, can be done clean and easily with a grid. I just picked "random" spacings. you can adjust the gaps to your likings. a grid can be used same as a table with few advantages and less efford on the HTML side.

had to change your HTML code a bit. class="outer" is now the grid wrapper and everything else that was not needed got deleted so that all labels and input fields are now direct childrens of .outer. Otherwise a Grid will not apply cleanly.

```css
.outer {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
}

#title {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  text-align: right;
}

#title_field  {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

#category  {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  text-align: right;
}

#cat_field  {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

#img_placeholder {
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
}

#lease  {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  text-align: right;
}

#lease_field  {
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>houseform</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class = "outer">
    <label id = "title">Title</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "title_field" class = "small_output_field">
    <label id = "category">Category</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "cat_field" class = "small_output_field">
    <div id = "img_placeholder"></div>
    <label id = "lease">LeaseNumber</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "lease_field" class = "long_output_field">
  </div>    
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that way...

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flexDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.long_output_field {
  width: 15%;
}

#img_placeholder {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.form_fields_long {
  width: 100%;
}
.long_output_field {width: 300px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>houseform</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="flexDiv">
      <div class="form_fields_short">
        <label id="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" id="title_field" class="small_output_field">
      </div>
      <div class="form_fields_short">
        <label id="category">Category</label>
        <input type="text" id="cat_field" class="small_output_field">
      </div>
      <div id="img_placeholder">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_fields_long">
      <label id="lease">LeaseNumber</label>
      <input type="text" id="lease_field" class="long_output_field">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using grid layout with grid-areas. This is more readable and easy to understand.

```css
.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
  padding:10px 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 0.5fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "title title_field category cat_field image"
    ". . . . ."
    "lease lease_field lease_field lease_field  .";
}
.title{
  grid-area:title;
}
#title_field{
  grid-area:title_field;
  margin-left:.5rem;
}
.lease{
  grid-area:lease;
}
#lease_field{
  grid-area:lease_field;
  margin-left:.5rem;
}
.category{
  grid-area:category;
  padding-left:2rem;
}
#cat_field{
  grid-area:cat_field;
  margin-left:.5rem;
  
}


#img_placeholder {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
  grid-area:image;
  margin-left:2rem;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="title">
    <label id="title">Title</label>
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="title_field" class="small_output_field">

  <div class="category">
    <label id="category">Category</label>
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="cat_field" class="small_output_field">

  <div id="img_placeholder">
    İmage
  </div>

  <div class="lease">
    <label id="lease">LeaseNumber</label>
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="lease_field" class="long_output_field">

</div>
```